# Crystal Report not working on IIS port:80

Tags: iis, iis-7, crystal-reports

I have deployed my Web Application locally in organization on IIS 7.0, port:80, so that I can access the application from any PC on the local network.

Everything else is working fine but Crystal Reports wants a UserName and Password on both the Network as well as on the local machine.

When I change the port of the application from `80` to `81` or `82`, then it works fine, showing each report.

I have copied the `asp_client` folder from `wwwroot` folder to my `Published Application`, but it still not working.

My question is, which Port Number should I configure `IIS` so that I can access my application on the local network and also view Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, by Changing the **Port** of **Reporting Services Configuration Manager** which was also running on **Port:80** by default.

```
Step 1 : Type Reporting Service Configuration Manager in Run.
Step 2 : Go to Web Service URL and change TCP Port.
Step 3 : Go to Report Manager URL and go the Advance and Edit the Port Number.
Step 4 : Save it, and all is Done.
```